# CMake and PyArrow Errors While Installing Streamlit

Tags: python, cmake, streamlit, pyarrow

During the installation of Streamlit using the 'pip install streamlit' command, I encountered errors related to both CMake and PyArrow. The process failed with the following error messages:

```
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
error: command '/usr/local/bin/cmake' failed with exit code 1
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:261 (find_package):
    By not providing "FindArrow.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
    asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Arrow", but
    CMake did not find one.
    Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Arrow" with any of
    the following names:
      ArrowConfig.cmake
      arrow-config.cmake
Add the installation prefix of "Arrow" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
"Arrow_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files. If "Arrow"
provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
installed.
```

PyArrow Error:

```
ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyarrow
Failed to build pyarrow
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyarrow, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

The installation process fails with the above-mentioned CMake error related to 'pyarrow'.
I have attempted reinstalling CMake and pyarrow, but the error persists.
My python version is 3.10.0